# Rails websocket connection ID storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket-rails

I search the [Web socket rails gem](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails) but could not figure out weather the connection ID of a channel is stored on redis server or is stored on the rails memory. Any one has any idea where it is stored.

Basically we want to scale our server by adding more instances and thats the reasons we want to make sure that a users's connection ID or mapping of Channels and connection ID is stored on redis and not on the rails application server.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that gem, but as far as I can see on their code:

https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/blob/master/lib/websocket_rails/channel.rb

The identifier for a channel is the `@name` and that will be accessible through Rails. Not sure if that helps. Maybe if you give an example of what do you want to do with the channel id someone can help

Comment: Basically we want to scale our server by adding more instances and thats the reasons we want to make sure that a users's connection ID is stored on redis and not on the rails application server.